# Is there software that allows employees to make their own site (on the company domain) without the ability to mess up the rest of the site?

Tags: wysiwyg

I manage a site for a school and the staff (teachers specifically) use the site [Weebly](http://www.weebly.com/) to create a personal site to inform students of new assignments, or embed content like lesson plans for students who may have missed class, etc. I looked at CMS like [Bolt](https://bolt.cm/) but I don't know if that is what I really need. What I want is to give them sub domains of the main site, like `teacher.example.com` or `example.com\teacher` where they can edit their own small portion of the site and update it to meet their needs. They only need the ability to edit text and maybe upload a picture or two, the sites will follow the general formatting of the framework being used currently. Preferably the second option `example.com\teacher` is much easier to manage because getting sub domain access (from the county) is a hassle. Please also note that these are teachers who are not fluent in any coding so a WYSIWYG editor is a *must*.

Comment: schoolmessenger.com/cms-for-schools looks slick and professional - and probably not free, although I can't see any indication of pricing

Comment: Education focused CMSs http://www.cmswire.com/cms/web-experience/5-educationfocused-web-content-management-platforms-021526.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at **[Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/)**, and its feature called "**[Multi-Site](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site)**" to share the same code base with as many sites as you'd want. In your case you could have 1 such site for each teacher (and the WYSIWYG editor you're looking for is typically implemented using the [CK Editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module).

Maybe you also want to investigate the available Drupal "**[Distributions](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_distribution)**", which provide site features and functions for a specific type of site as a single download containing Drupal core, contributed modules, themes, and pre-defined configuration. They make it possible to quickly set up a complex, use-specific site in fewer steps than if installing and configuring elements individually.

For (a lot of) suggestions about using "Drupal as a LMS", refer to my answer to the question "[Drupal as a LMS. Learning platforms based on Drupal, or integrated with it](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65294/drupal-as-a-lms-learning-platforms-based-on-drupal-or-integrated-with-it/166439#166439)"

Comment: Yup, I love Drupal. But I also appreciate the CMS selection wizard and CMS comparision features at http://cmsmatrix.org/ which surprisingly few people seem to know about

Comment: Thank you so much! I just took a look at Drupal, and I must say that it looks quite good. I've already started trying I get it integrated into the website and it looks as though it will perform nicely for this! Also, thank you to all the other responses to my problem!

Comment: Thank you for your accept ... I just realized I forgot to +1 your interesting question also, which is what I just did ... If you have more (drupal) related questions when moving forward on this, leave a comment around here if you want to bring that to my attention also!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a major difference between primary and secondary schools?

Disclaimer: I am not a teacher (although I did go to school with children), so I have not personally tried this product. Btw, it was surprisingly easy to find (GIYF). Try the demo and see if it is for you. It certainly seems to meet your needs.

> What is [SyndeoCMS](http://www.syndeocms.org/)?
>
> A Content Management System (CMS) for primary
>   schools, which helps you manage and maintain your website. It can also
>   be a very usefull CMS for small companies or non profit organizations.
>
> It is Open Source Software (that means free to use), licensed under
>   the General Public license. Syndeocms is my continuation of
>   Site@School 2.4.10. see History for more details.
>
> Main features are:
>   - You can manage a website without technical knowledge.
>   - It has an editor with a high "Word look and feel" rate (FCKeditor).
>   - **Pupils and teachers can have personal pages on the website.**
>   - Teachers can check pupil pages before publication.
>   - Project   pages for pupils and teachers.
>   -  An intranet for teachers which is not  accessible by the public.
>   - A lot of modules (like a guestbook and newsletter) for your website, see available Modules Template editor or
>   you can create your own template, see creating templates 
>   - is LAMP or  WAMP compatible (i.e., Linux or Windows server)
>   - Backup feature to make  a local backup of the mysql database.
>   -  Translation tool to change the language files to your needs or create a new translation.
>   - And much  more.
>
> How do I get started You could try our [demo site](http://www.syndeocms.org/demo/) and look for yourself if the system suites you.

Answer (score 0):

If I may recommend [WordPress](http://wordpress.org), it too has a feature called multi-site which always to create subdomains off an existing domain where you can give access to specific sites for specific employees. It's open source and very easy to use and setup. It also includes a very easy to use page/post editor and you can also add plugins that add functionality to this editor as well.